# How does this message splitting work?

Tags: cryptography, rsa

I have been trying to reverse engineer various encryption algorithms in compiled code recently, and I came upon this code. It is a part of a RSA algorithm. I've noted that the key size is too small to encrypt/decrypt the data it's supposed to (in this case an `int`), so the code splits the message into two pieces, and encrypt/decrypt each, then sum them together. I've pulled the segments of code that splits and joins the message, and experimented with it. It appears that the numerical values that it uses is dependent on the `n` modulus. So, what exactly is this scheme, and how does it work?

```
uint n = 32437;
uint origVal = 12345;
uint newVal = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
    ulong num = (ulong)origVal * 43827549;
    //uint num2 = ((origVal - (uint)(num >> 32)) / 2 + (uint)(num >> 32)) >> 14;
    uint num2 = (origVal + (uint)(num >> 32)) / 32768;
    origVal -= num2 * n;                
    // RSA encrypt/decrypt here
    newVal *= n;
    newVal += origVal;
    origVal = num2;
}

// Put newVal into origVal, to reverse
origVal = newVal;
newVal = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
    ulong num = (ulong)origVal * 43827549;
    //uint num2 = ((origVal - (uint)(num >> 32)) / 2 + (uint)(num >> 32)) >> 14;
    uint num2 = (origVal + (uint)(num >> 32)) / 32768;
    origVal -= num2 * n;                
    // RSA encrypt/decrypt here
    newVal *= n;
    newVal += origVal;
    origVal = num2;
}
```

Note: it seems the operations applied are symmetric.

Comment: hmm it looks like fixed point arithmetic, not like crypto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using various values for `origVal`, I've found out that the first three lines after the `for` loop is just a division, with the line immediately after that a modulo operation. The lines

```
ulong num = (ulong)origVal * 43827549;
//uint num2 = ((origVal - (uint)(num >> 32)) / 2 + (uint)(num >> 32)) >> 14;
uint num2 = (origVal + (uint)(num >> 32)) / 32768;
```

translates into

```
uint valDivN = origVal / n;
```

and

```
origVal -= num2 * n;
```

into

```
origVal = origVal % n;
```

So the final code inside the `for` loop looks like this:

```
uint valDivN = origVal / n;
origVal = origVal % n;
// RSA encrypt/decrypt here
newVal*= n;
newVal+= origVal;
origVal = valDivN;
```

### Analysis

This code splits values by taking the modulo of the original value, transforming it, then multiplying it by `n`, and tacking the transformation of the previous quotient onto the result. The lines `uint valDivN = origVal / n;` and `newVal*= n;` form inverse operations. You can think of the input message as having two "boxes". After the loop has run through, you get the transformed value put in opposite "boxes". When the message is decrypted, the two values in the "boxes" are reverse transformed, and put in their original spots in the "boxes". The reason the divisor is `n` is to keep the value being encrypted/decrypted under `n`, as the maximum value you can encrypt with RSA is no larger than `n`. There is no possibility of the wrong value being decrypted, as the code processes the packed message and extracts the part that should be decrypted prior to decrypting. The loop only runs twice because there is no chance for the quotient to exceed the size of an `int` (since the input is an `int`).